# ¿Es "e hiere" o "y hiere"?

Tags: gramática, conjunciones

El título de una noticia de primera plana en un periódico local importante es:

> Hombre mata a un hijo **e hiere** a otro.

Yo estoy 99.5% seguro que eso es un disparate. Tengo entendido que debe ser *Hombre mata a un hijo ***y hiere*** a otro*.

Para confirmar, ¿debe decir "e hiere" o "y hiere"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Llevas razón, debe ser **y hiere**.

Según la RAE en [*Cambio de la y copulativa en e*](http://www.rae.es/consultas/cambio-de-la-y-copulativa-en-e):

> La conjunción copulativa y toma la forma e ante palabras que empiezan por el sonido vocálico /i/ (i- o hi- en la escritura): *Eres único e irrepetible*; *Necesito aguja e hilo*.

Y luego detalla las...

> Excepciones:
>
> Cuando al sonido /i/ le sigue una vocal con la que forma diptongo: *La mesa es de madera y hierro* (no de madera e hierro).

El ejemplo que da coincide con la palabra que tú planteas: *hiere*. En ella, el sonido /i/ es seguido por una /e/, con la que forma un diptongo. Así decimos */y-ie-re/*.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta.

Comment: Lo muy interesante es eso de «una vocal con la que forma diptongo», como es posible un comienzo de /i.V/ (con hiato) y se supone que en tal caso aún se necesitaría la E.  Pero como puede ser algo variable el (no) hiato, puede haber palabras que aceptan las dos formas.  Tal caso sería, imagino, con todas las palabras que derivan de *ion* (que antes aceptaba las grafías *ion* e *ión*, o bien, *ión* y *ion* ;-) )